# Empezar en 0 en el eje Y usando chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Estoy usando chart.js y creando un grafico line.
Los datos que quiero mostrar son {"2020":"373","2021":"523","2022":"304"}
El grafico se muestra de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La configuración que tengo es:

```
var lineChartCitasTotales = new Chart("speedCanvas", {
    type: 'line',
    data: {"2020":"373","2021":"523","2022":"304"},
    options: 
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'top',
                labels: {
                    boxWidth: 80,
                    fontColor: 'black'
                }
            }
});
```

¿Cómo puedo configurar el gráfico para que el eje Y, empiece desde 0, y no desde el valor más pequeño que quiero mostrar?.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Prueba agregando esto a las options:

```
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias masterguru. No me ha funcionado, pero me ha indicado por donde buscar la solución. Imagino que será por las versiones del Char.js. Responderé a mi misma pregunta con la solución que he encontrado para mi caso.

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que te haya servido al menos para encontrar tu solución :-)

Answer (score 1):

que con su respuesta me encaminó a lo que debía de buscar.
La solución que en mi caso me ha funcionado, ha sido agregar lo siguiente a las options:

```
           scales:{
                yAxes:[{
                    ticks: { 
                        beginAtZero :true
                    }
                }]
            },
```